# eslint-plugin-import: for js files not svg or css

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint

I am using eslint import plugin with eslint.

I am importing images and SVG inline from source files but my linting gives me a warning:

```
No default export found in module              import/default
```

I want to switch off the warning but only for non-"*.js" values. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you are talking about the `import/ignore` setting.

Docs: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#importignore